# Tizen gcc assembler generating ELFs instead of object files -- cannot create static library

Tags: gcc, static-libraries, elf, tizen

I am trying to build zlib with the [Tizen](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiD76yrpdXPAhVG4iYKHW_8Dr4QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tizen.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNFj_FfKbOJbXdrgogNHRQ36nKwsMQ&sig2=VmVGB-h7N038YE-VDa84jg) tool set.  As part of the build process, the source files are supposed to be compiled into objects with `arm-linux-gnu-eabi-gcc -c`, and then combined into an archive with `libtool`, but `libtool` fails and complains that each of the `.o` files passed to it `is not an object file (not allowed in a library)`.

Upon inspection, I find that `arm-linux-gnu-eabi-gcc -c` is generating ELF files rather than object files, something I haven't seen before.  When I pass `-c -v` to the compiler, I can see that the linker is not being invoked.  So why the ELF format?

I then tried invoking `arm-linux-gnu-eabi-gcc -S` followed by `arm-linux-gnu-eabi-as`, and found out that the assembler itself is generating ELF files.

Here's an example:

```
% echo "int main(void) { return 0; }" > main.c
% arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc main.c -S -o main.s
% arm-linux-gnueabi-as main.s -o main.o
% file main.o
main.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

The Tizen tool set includes four compilers ({i386,arm} and {4.6,4.9}).  All four behave the same way.

At least this `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` is consistent, because I can pass it a number of `.o` ELF files and it seems to link them properly.  But I still need to be able to generate real object files so that they can be archived into a static library with `libtool`.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is generating ELF files rather than object files,

You are *very* confused: `ELF` and object files are not exclusive, and on Linux *all* object files are `ELF`. In other words, this is working as expected.

`ELF` files can have different type: `ET_REL` (relocatable *object* files), `ET_DYN` (shared libraries) and `ET_EXEC` (executables).

> I still need to be able to generate real object files so that they can be archived into a static library with libtool

The problem is likely that `libtool` doesn't recognize non-native `ELF` `.o` files as something it can put into an archive library.

In general, `libtool` is almost always the *wrong* solution to the problem, regardless of what the problem is. Its [stated goal](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/) is to "hide the complexity of using shared libraries behind a consistent, portable interface". In my experience, it spectacularly fails to achieve that goal on all platforms.

Certainly if you *just* want to put a bunch of `.o` files into an archive library, the right way to do that is to simply use `*-linux-gnueabi-ar` which should have no problem.

Comment: Interesting thoughts on `libtool`.  I haven't really used it myself, but many projects seem to use it, and I'm using it here simply because `zlib` wants it.

Comment: I think I knew that objects were `ELF` files, but had forgotten that in the blow-by-blow with the build process.  Thank you for the explanation.  I ended up solving the problem by ensuring that environment variable `AR` was properly defined, so that `libtool` could invoke the non-native `ar` that you referred to.